# Where can I find a current EJB tutorial?

Tags: java, ejb-3.1

Here on StackOVerflow I read that we shouldnt use `Remote` and `Local` interface inheritance for EJB server appllication and more, we shouldnt use deployment XML files any more.

So what are the main steps now (2013) for creating a complete EJB simple "Hello World" application? Is there any tutorial which explains it step by step for people for whom its a totally new thing? Cheers

What I found on the Internet is that the newest EJB standard is EJB 3.1. - is that correct?

Comment: have you tried googling?  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24446/ejbs.htm)  and [here](http://tomee.apache.org/ejb-31-tutorial.html) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSR-345](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_2-fr-spec/index.html) defines the 3.2 version of the ejb specification

Conceptually the added features from 3.1/3.0 are not significant, so most tutorials you find for those versions will still be ok.

anyways, a recent tutorial can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-gettingstarted001.htm)

Comment: Many thanks! Thats the page I was looking for: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partentbeans.htm!

Answer (score 2):

EJB has really fallen out of favor.  I recommend listing out what benefits you are looking for and see if there are simpler ways of doing them,  in many cases there are.  Are you sure you need to go EJB?  Try looking at http://spring.io/.

Answer (score 0):

> So what are the main steps now (2013) for creating a complete EJB
>   simple "Hello World" application? Is there any tutorial which explains
>   it step by step for people for whom its a totally new thing?

You have a lot of tutorials on oracle site.

> What I found on the Internet is that the newest EJB standard is EJB
>   3.1. - is that correct?

Yes, latest EJB (at this moment) is EJB 3.1.